# ajax call not being made from within <p:dataGrid>

Tags: ajax, jsf, datagrid, primefaces

**I read BalusC's post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)) too but still unable to make an ajax call from a dataGrid.
Is it that dataGrid doesn support ajax calls? Or i missed something?**

Tried everything, the method gets hit when outside the dataGrid, so I assume something do to with dataGrid..? First my page was included into a template, I removed that, still no luck.

**My jsf :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>Order select</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:400px;" id="layout">  

                        <p:layoutUnit id="rightLayout" position="east" size="100" minSize="200" maxSize="200">  
                            right
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center" >  

                            <h:form id="imgForm" style="text-align: center">

                                <p:dataGrid var="img" 
                                            value="#{orderBean.userMedia.mediaList}" 
                                            columns="4"  
                                            rows="16" 
                                            paginator="true"  
                                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                                            rowsPerPageTemplate="9,12,15">  

                                    <p:panel>
                                        <p:commandLink actionListener="#{orderBean.selectImage}" update="@form">
                                            <p:graphicImage value="#{img.thumbNail.getString('url')}"/>
                                        </p:commandLink>
                                    </p:panel>

                                </p:dataGrid> 

                            </h:form>  

                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>  

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**My managed bean(viewScoped) method:**

```
public void selectImage()
    {
        String methodName = "selectImage()";
        log.info("Entering :"+methodName);
    }
```

**I am using :**
primefaces : 3.3.1
(tomcat 7 + Java 1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in primefaces docs, you have to put everything inside `p:datagrid` inside a `p:column`

```
<p:dataGrid var="img" 
            value="#{orderBean.userMedia.mediaList}" 
            columns="4"  
            rows="16" 
            paginator="true"  
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
            rowsPerPageTemplate="9,12,15">  
     <p:column>
         <p:panel>
             <p:commandLink actionListener="#{orderBean.selectImage}" update="@form">
                 <p:graphicImage value="#{img.thumbNail.getString('url')}"/>
              </p:commandLink>
         </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Starting from primefaces version 3.4, this is not required, but you are using version 3.3.1